# Why don't we say what the Yerushalmi says to say during Bircat Kohanim?

Tags: birchas-kohanim, tractate-brachot, talmud-yerushalmi

I've been studying [the Talmud Yerushalmi Berachot, which](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r1101.htm) lists what you should say during Bircat Kohanim:

> אמר רבי הונא זה שרואה את הכהנים בבית הכנסת בברכה ראשונה צריך לומר ברכו את ה׳ מלאכיו בשנייה ברכו את ה׳ כל צבאיו בשלישית ברכו ה׳ כל מעשיו
>
> Rabbi Huna said: One who sees the Kohanim in the synagogue — in the first blessing he must say "Bless God, O his messengers"; in the second, "Bless God, O all his troops"; in the third, "Bless God, O all his creations".

As far as I'm aware, there's nothing about that in the Talmud Bavli. If there is no dispute on that, why don't we say what the Yerushalmi says to say?

Comment: You will find almost the identical quote in Sota 39b half way down the page. http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l3507.htm

Comment: It's not the same quotes. And even if they were, it wouldn't explain why we don't say anything at all.

Comment: See Berachos (in the beginning of the 9 th chapter) where it says our text

Comment: @avram, Danny wasn't arguing or answering the question, just posting a comment that may provide additional insight to the OP or a potential answerer. I don't understand why you are challenging him.

Comment: @AvramLevitt: I was commenting on your phrase: "As far as I'm aware, there's nothing about that in the Talmud Bavli." The line I referred you to is almost identical: 
בזמן שהכהנים מברכים את העם מה הן אומרים אמר ר' זירא אמר רב חסדא ברכו ה' מלאכיו גבורי כח וגו' ברכו ה' כל צבאיו משרתיו עושי רצונו ברכו ה' כל מעשיו בכל מקומות ממשלתו ברכי נפשי את ה' 
במוספי דשבתא מה הן אומרים אמר רבי אסי שיר המעלות הנה ברכו את ה' כל עבדי ה' וגו' שאו ידיכם קדש וברכו את ה'  ברוך ה' מציון שוכן ירושלים הללויה ולימא נמי יברכך ה' מציון דכתיב בההוא עניינא אמר יהודה בריה דר"ש בן פזי מתוך שהתחיל בברכותיו של ה מסיים בברכותיו

Comment: Do we always do like the Yerushalmi when there is no dispute?

Comment: I don't know. It seems like there would be no reason not to.

Comment: Well if you can show that we do like the Yerushalmi when there is no dispute then you have a question, otherwise I do not see a question here.

Comment: @DannySchoemann So it turns out that the Bavli on the next page explains why we don't say anything. Since you directed me towards that, you should put that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bavli on Sota 39b says that one should respond - and the wording there is almost identical to the Yerushalmi:

> בזמן שהכהנים מברכים את העם מה הן אומרים אמר ר' זירא אמר רב חסדא ברכו ה' מלאכיו גבורי כח וגו' ברכו ה' כל צבאיו משרתיו עושי רצונו ברכו ה' כל מעשיו בכל מקומות ממשלתו ברכי נפשי את ה' במוספי דשבתא מה הן אומרים אמר רבי אסי שיר המעלות הנה ברכו את ה' כל עבדי ה' וגו' שאו ידיכם קדש וברכו את ה' ברוך ה' מציון שוכן ירושלים הללויה ולימא נמי יברכך ה' מציון דכתיב בההוא עניינא אמר יהודה בריה דר"ש בן פזי מתוך שהתחיל בברכותיו של ה מסיים בברכותיו

However, on the next pager - Sota 40a - various Amoraim discuss whether the above applies only in the Bet Hamikdash - or whether it applies at all, since it seems incorrect to *talk back* while one is being given a Bracha.

> א"ר חייא בר אבא **כל האומרן בגבולין אינו אלא טועה** אמר רבי חנינא בר פפא **תדע דבמקדש נמי לא** מיבעי למימרינהו כלום **יש לך עבד שמברכין אותו ואינו מאזין** א"ר אחא בר חנינא תדע דבגבולין נמי מיבעי למימרינהו כלום יש עבד שמברכין אותו ואין מסביר פנים

It seems that the Rema on Orach Chaim 45 agrees that one should not *talk* during the Brachot - he says one should say the  רִבּוֹן for bad dreams only when the Cohanim are humming, and not while they say the actual blessings. However, in Siman 130:1 it seems that the Mechaber says to say it during the actual Birkat Cohanim.

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (100:13) is more explicit:

> בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁהַכֹּהֲנִים אוֹמְרִים אֶת הַתֵּבוֹת, **אֵין לַצִּבּוּר לוֹמַר שׁוּם פָּסוּק**, רַק יִשְׁמְעוּ הֵיטֵב בְּכַוָּנָה אֶת הַתֵּבוֹת מִפִּי הַכֹּהֲנִים, כִּי כְּלוּם יֵשׁ עֶבֶד שֶׁמְבָרְכִים אוֹתוֹ וְאֵינוֹ מַאֲזִין וּמְכַוֵּן לַבְּרָכָה. וְאִם אוֹמְרִים הַפְּסוּקִים, אֵינָם יְכוֹלִים לְכַוֵּן לַבְּרָכָה. אַךְ **קְצָת נוֹהֲגִים לוֹמַר פְּסוּקִים**. וְיִזָהֲרוּ שֶׁלֹּא לְאָמְרָם אֶלָּא בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁשְּׁלִיחַ הַצִבּוּר אוֹ הַכֹּהֲנִים מְנַגְּנִים, וְלֹא בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁאוֹמְרִים אֶת הַתֵּבוֹת.